# Error: "argument to 'which' is not logical" for sparse logical matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

Here's what I am doing:

1. Loading sparse matrix from a file.
2. Extracting indices(col, row) which have the values in this sparse matrix.
3. Use these indices and the values for further computation.

This works fine when I am executing the steps on R command prompt.
**But when its done inside a function of a package, step 2 throws the following error**:

```
Error in which(matA != 0, arr.ind = TRUE) :
  argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Here's the sample code with an example:

```
matA <- as(Matrix(c(0,1,2,1,0,0,3,0,2), nrow=3, ncol=3), "sparseMatrix")  # Step 1
nz <- which(matA != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)  # Step 2

> nz
     row col
[1,]   2   1
[2,]   3   1
[3,]   1   2
[4,]   1   3
[5,]   3   3
```

The loaded matrices in my case are of type: dsCMatrix, dgCMatrix.

```
class(matA != 0): lsCMatrix
```

I don't understand why should this lead to the error.

Please note the following:

1. Can't share the dumped sparse matrix file. Hence shown an example by creating a dummy matrix for step 1.
2. The dimensions of the sparse matrix are huge. So converting the sparse matrix to a regular matrix exceeds the memory limit.

**Libraries**:
The package that I am using mentions the following libraries:

```
Suggests: 
    testthat (>= 2.1.0),
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
Imports: 
    irlba,
    text2vec,
    dplyr,
    magrittr,
    Matrix,
    readr,
    rlang,
    data.table,
    stringr,
    here
```

Comment: Please state `library` calls.

Comment: @jay.sf Added the libraries mentioned in the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the library `Matrix`, chances are the package does not load it. See example below:

```
library(Seurat)
mat = pbmc_small@assays$RNA@counts
class(mat)
[1] "dgCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"

which(mat>0)
Error in which(mat > 0) : argument to 'which' is not logical

library(Matrix)
head(which(mat>0,arr.ind=TRUE))
         row col
CD79B      2   1
HLA-DQB1   6   1
LTB        9   1
SP100     12   1
CXCR4     23   1
CD3D      31   1
```

If Matrix is already loaded, it might be the Matrix::which is masked somehow. you can do:

```
Matrix::which(mat>0)
```

Comment: Inside the function, I have added `print(dim(matA))`.   
And the script prints the following statement just before executing the above line: **Loading required package: Matrix**  
So I guess the issue is not what you had mentioned.

Comment: Ok hey, I tested it, there's no reason for it not to work. Can you try calling the which explicitly, using Matrix::which(matA > 0)

Comment: You are right. Explicitly calling **Matrix::which** worked. Seems the script was using **which** of another library.  
Thanks a lot.